# Indicator Function Examples

Tags: integration, functions

I get the definition of indicator functions but how would I give an example of one?
Indicator function is defined for a set $C$ as,

$$I_{C}(x) =\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \in C \\
   0       & \text{if } x \not\in C
  \end{cases}$$

How would I show an example of this where a set $C ⊂ R$ which need not be an interval?

Comment: If you know how to give an example of  set $C$ you have an example of an indicator function.

Comment: Can I just say let C=(0,5)

Comment: Yes, of course.